# Grails default timezone nature while building API

Tags: mysql, web-services, api, grails, groovy

I am using grails 2.4.4 for building a restful API. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out grails default time-zone settings.
The premise of the problem is I am using default grails setting without using and dateBinders in config.groovy and the timezone of my both mysql and application server is in NPT.

So I am posting a json something like

```
{"clusterStartTime":"2015-10-15T17:45:00Z"}
```

Now this is a **ISO 8601** format. So how can this date format represent my timezone so grails can interpret it ??

In database it is being saved as `2015-10-15 17:45:00`.
But when I get this resource I am getting :

```
{"clusterStartTime": "2015-10-15T12:00:00Z"}
```

So I am getting a time with offset of 5:45 which is NPT offset. So how is grails doing all of this ??

So in production I have a server in NPT timezone so how can I save all my dates in UTC timezone and spit out dates in UTC timezone using grails only without setting Java enviroment variables ??

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap.groovy set the timezone like this:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Katmandu"))
```

`NTP` is not supported directly. To get a list of supported timezones see the output of `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

In order to interpret correctly any ISO 8601 date you have to use a good parser. The one provided by [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) should be good enough. The method [`parseDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) expects a [`lexicalXSDDateTime`](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html), which must be ISO 6801 compliant.

Therefore try this:

```
    def cal = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime('2015-10-15T17:45:00Z')
    def d = cal.getTime()
    def t1 = new TestClass(myDate: d).save(failOnError:true)
    println t1.myDate //Thu Oct 15 17:45:00 NPT 2015
```

The date gets saved on the database (e.g. in a `DATETIME` field) considering the time zone you defined, so it should be correct when you retrieve it.

Comment: sorry for late reply but when I set my application's timezone to UTC, and save to mysql server it offsets it by 5:45 hrs (date saved in mysql is different than the one posted). Note my machine timezone is in NPT. How do you tackle that ??